# redux: getting rid of boilerplate when updating reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

Suppose you are creating a product and saving product's property in a reducer.

When product has a few properties, you could define `action type` for updating each property and a `case` handler inside reducer to update the property.

For example, `ACTION_TYPE_UPDATE_PRODUCT_NAME` `ACTION_TYPE_UPDATE_PRODUCT_TYPE` and so on.

But as the number of properties increases, this practice results in a lot of code just to save the properties inside reducer.

I would just define one `update product action`.
Then I would just grab current product from the reducer, update fields as I needed, and store the product back in reducer with the `update product action`.

Is this approach sane and are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action you can define as below:

```
const update_product_field = ({ prop, value, id }) => {
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPE_UPDATE_PRODUCT,
    payload: { prop, value, id }
  };
};
```

Then in your reducer you can define the case as below:

```
case ACTION_TYPE_UPDATE_PRODUCT:
  return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
```

There is no right or wrong answer for your scenario, just depending on how abstract you can write your actions and reducers

Answer (score 1):

You can update as many properties as you need in one action. For example you updated user data and new properties are { username: 'New Name', city: 'New City' }. You should not update each property in a separate action. Just update whole user object with a set of new properties.

```
updateUserData(state, action) {
    return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, username: action.username, city: action.city } }
```